# Is Wordpress API visible from PHP file called in htaccess

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls, htaccess, api

I'm trying to add some rewriterules in the .htaccess file to deal with hotlinked images - specifically I want to add the URL from the post where the image appeared to the header location information of the hotlinked image request.

I've got working htaccess & PHP code to add the header info, but in order to make it work, I need to be able to somehow look up the URL for the post from the image URL (this blog has a unique post for each image). I've got working code to do this, but it uses the Wordpress API, and when I try to call it none of the functions are recognized.

I'm thinking that maybe calling the API from htaccess isn't possible... like it's out of scope, or I'm calling from a place that can't see Wordpress or something? I'm wondering if there's a way to make Wordpress API calls accessible from htaccess - or if anybody has any suggestions for a workaround.

The only thing I can think of would be to try to query the database directly through MySQL, but I'm a bit nervous about doing that, and I'm not quite sure I understand the data structure fully.

Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: Try using the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) instead of .htaccess. Here's a [great tutorial](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api)

Comment: You can also try including the `wp-load.php` file from the root of your WordPress installation to access the WordPress API

Answer (score 2):

The `.htaccess` is parsed before WordPress is loaded, so you don’t get access to WordPress data.

You can make the redirect in WordPress, in a plugin: Hook into `404_template` and inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` with [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). You should be able to find the matching post for the image then.
You did not write how the permalinks for these posts are built, so we cannot offer a more specific solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I fear I am a tad bit too inept to be able to implement it at this point (total newbie to WP programming) so I went with rrikesh's down and dirty solution. But thanks - maybe someday I'll be accomplished enough to get there! :-)

Answer (score 1):

To access your WordPress functions within a standalone PHP file, add the two following lines at the beginning of your PHP file:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require('wp-blog-header.php'); # or modify to match your current wp-blog-header.php file
```